# How do you extract data from a website's HTML code when its source code doesn't contain any text that appears on the site?

Tags: html

I'm trying to extract data from a particular site but when I read through the html code it contains none of the text that appears on the webpage. And all the webpages have the same code as the home page. I was wondering if it is possible to 'hide' data on your webpage somehow, and how I might be able to find it.
Thanks!

Comment: Your question is very general and no one can answer you unless you provide more details about your question. but just to let you know, no, you can not hide anything in the `HTML` content of the site. maybe the webpage you are trying to extract data from is using `iframe` or `ajax` to load data fater the main page loads on client-side.

Comment: that might be a dynamic data coming from ajax.you cant see dynamic data when you see the page source.Instead you open developer tools in your browser and inspect the elements.